# Почему старушек называют "Божий одуванчик"?

Tags: фразеология

О старушках часто говорят "Божий одуванчик". А откуда пошло это выражение и почему их так называют?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, от того, что они хотят под Богом, который в любой момент может их "одуть" их седые головки... Грусноватый в общем-то юморок получается, но такое в языке встречается.

Answer (score 4):

Божьими одуванчиками в равной степени называют и старушек, и старичков. Седая пушистая голова и глубоко почтенный возраст однозначно рождают подобный образ. Бают, что впервые в литературе употребил этот фразеологизм Михаил Зощенко в своем рассказе :

> "Зощенко способен на многое, но ему
> следовало бы не забывать, что лучшее,
> сказанное им, «**старушка, божий одуванчик**», а
> не «собачка системы пудель».
> (Максим Горький)

Одуванчик в стародавние времена величали - **попово гуменцо**, очень характерное имячко.

Просто с одуванчиками также сравнивали писатели стариков:

М. П. Арцыбашев. Смерть Ланде (1904)  Ланде вошел тихо; голова у него через щеку и глаз была повязана толстым белым бинтом и казалась уродливо громадной, **как исполинский белый одуванчик**, покачивающийся на тоненьком шатком стебельке.

Е. И. Замятин. Север (1918) Выполз из землянки, стоит― козырьком руку к глазам, капельный, ряска зелёненькая, в руках― шапка-мурмолка, на голове― пушок белый: дунь― **облетит, как одуванчик.**

В общем, ответственным именно за *божьего одуванчика* великий Горький назвал писателя Зощенко, с последнего и спрос!

Answer (score 2):

Нашла интересную статью на эту тему http://znaniya2011.ru/otkuda-poshli-vyirazheniya/otkuda-poshli-vyirazheniya-bozhiy-oduvanchik

Comment: Надюшка, я не имею ничего против любых статей как таковх, но с большим подозрением отношусь к этимологическим версиям, для обоснования которых надо привлечь столько второстепенных деталей. И врачей вспомнили, и священников, и больных и болезнь конретную назвали - и стаистику выздоровлений - и даже "прическу" после. 
Непонятно только, почему все это должно относиться именно к старушкам. 
После тифа все в общем-то равны. А если без него, то старики обычно выглядят покрепче старушек одного с ними возраста, хотя и живут меньше.

Comment: Мне просто понравилось объясние. О достоверности... Все неоднозначно. Больше похоже на художественный рассказ. Но почему бы нет? )))